# How do I configure my MVC app to run in iis integrated mode?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer, integrated-pipeline-mode

How do I configure my MVC app so that the Visual Studio development server runs it in integrated pipeline mode?

Comment: why not just run it on local IIS in Integrated Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't believe the Web Development Server supports that. If you want to test under integrated mode, you'll need to install IIS or IIS Express, create a Web Application, and tell Visual Studio to use the Local IIS server.